# Modify element in array. Deleting part of element in array. Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I need to get just the title of these songs out of a text file that has all of its info.  The text file looks like this.

```
TRMMCAU128F9332597<SEP>SOEEWIZ12AB0182B09<SEP>YGGDRASIL<SEP>Beyond the Borders of Sanity
TRMMCCS12903CBEA4A<SEP>SOARHKB12AB0189EEA<SEP>Illegal Substance<SEP>Microphone Check
```

So the title would be the "Beyond the Borders of Sanity" and "Microphone Check"

I cannot figure out how to delete all that stuff before it.  Here is the code i have so far:

```
# Checks for the argument, fail if none given
if(songs.txt != 0) {
print STDERR "You must specify the file name as the argument.\n";
exit 4;
}

# Opens the file and assign it to handle INFILE
open(INFILE, 'songs.txt') or die "Cannot open songs.txt: $!.\n";

@data = <INFILE>;

my @lines = map {$_ =~ /^T/ ? ($_ => 1) : ()} @data;

# This loops through each line of the file
#while($line = <INFILE>) {

#chomp;
#   print $line;
#   print @data; 

#}

# Close the file handle
close INFILE; 
print @lines;
```

It outputs this:

```
1TRMMCAU128F9332597<SEP>SOEEWIZ12AB0182B09<SEP>YGGDRASIL<SEP>Beyond the Borders of Sanity1
```

I realize the 1's dont do anything I was just playing around with it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Since the strange text that preceeds the data you want is of variable length, you will need to explain the rules necessary to recognize the end of this text.  The rest will be easy.

Comment: Is `<SEP>` literally in the file or is that your meta-notation for some other separator?

Comment: The <SEP> is literally in the file yes.  And What Jim Garrisson poster worked flawlessly.  Thank you very much.  I am still a newbie with perl and I can't seem to get the hang of it quite yet but I am getting there.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `split` function

```
@songs = map { chomp; (split /<SEP>/)[3] } @data;
```

Assuming `<SEP>` is literally in the file and you want the fourth delimited field, as it appears from the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like data from the [Million Song Dataset](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/sites/default/files/AdditionalFiles/unique_tracks.txt), which uses a literal `<SEP>` as the field delimiter.  To get the last field--the song's title--you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "You must specify the file name as the argument.\n";

while (<>) {
    print $1 if /([^>]+)$/;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl songs.txt [>outFile.txt]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
Beyond the Borders of Sanity
Microphone Check
```

The regex matches all characters from the end of the line that are not `>`, and captures them.  If the match is successful, the capture (stored in `$1`) is printed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This fails if there are more than four fields in an input record (i.e. there's a `<SEP>` and more data after the song title).

Comment: @JimGarrison - Indeed it would, but there's no evidence in the OP's representative data of more than four fields. `split`ting could also be a problem, if a field was added to the beginning in later data.